# AS3 bitmapdata.draw without adding to display list/ Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I want to be able to cahce HTML text as bitmap, for use in AlivePDF. My testing works well with TextArea or if the component is on the Stage or visible. But I want to be able to crunch text blocks that dont necessarily sit on screen. Does anyone know how to do this?

What I have failing so far

```
    public static function rasterizeText( text:String, width:int = 100, height:int = 100, x:int = 0, y:int = 0 ):BitmapData {
        var textRenderer:TextArea = new TextArea();
        textRenderer.width = width;
        textRenderer.height = height;
        textRenderer.htmlText = text;

        var bitdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0xFF000000)
        bitdata.draw( textRenderer );
        return bitdata;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how you can save a bitmap data without first generating it. Try rendering the text are at some point off the stage where it isn't visible & then remove it later.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine. There is no need to add textRenderer to the stage in order to draw it into the BitmapData. You are drawing your textRenderer onto a solid black background. Maybe your text is also black and that is why you can not see it?

Try changing 0xFF000000 to e.g. 0xFFFF0000 and see if the text will show up.

Comment: I don't think it's a colour issue, it only seems to work once I've added it to the Stage (below works, remove canvas and draw renderer doesn't)

`public function rasterizeText( text:String, width:int = 100, height:int = 100 ):BitmapData {
 var textRenderer:TextArea = new TextArea();
 textRenderer.width = width;
 textRenderer.height = height;
 textRenderer.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT); 
 canvas.rawChildren.addChild( textRenderer ); 
 var bitdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData( width, height, false )
 bitdata.draw( canvas );
 return bitdata;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

No it wasn't a color issue. Also I had the color set to FF000000 which at least should have been showing up black. TextArea didn't seem to play nice with bitmaps, although TextField works perfectly fine.

Edit: I'm guessing TextArea wasn't working as spark or mx because they're a FlexSprite thingy, which act differently to normal AS3 Sprites. They'll defer rendering until they're added to the display list.

Working function:

```
public function rasterizeText( text:String,
        width:int = 100, height:int = 100 ):BitmapData {
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.multiline = true;
    tf.wordWrap = true;
    tf.width = width;
    tf.height = height;
    tf.htmlText = text;
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true,0x00000000);
    bd.draw(tf);
    return bd;
}
```

This was not working (I tried mx & spark textarea components):

```
public function rasterizeText( text:String,
        width:int = 100, height:int = 100 ):BitmapData {
    var textRenderer:TextArea = new TextArea();
    textRenderer.width = width;
    textRenderer.height = height;
    textRenderer.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow( text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT );
    var bitdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData( width, height, false, 0xFF000000 )
    bitdata.draw( textRenderer );
    return bitdata;
}
```

However it would work when drawing from the Stage:

```
public function rasterizeText( text:String,
        width:int = 100, height:int = 100 ):BitmapData {
    var textRenderer:TextArea = new TextArea();
    textRenderer.width = width;
    textRenderer.height = height;
    textRenderer.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow( text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT );
    canvas.addElement( textRenderer );
    var bitdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData( width, height, false, 0xFF000000 )
    bitdata.draw( canvas );
    return bitdata;
}
```